# Finding 1918 birth certificate for Lviv

Tags: birth-records, poland, 1910s

Where do I start looking for a birth certificate for my father born in Lviv

Fathers surname Mandel name aka Zygfryd born Lviv 19/01/1918

Comment: Is your father's name `Zygfryd`, and surname `Mandel` ?

Answer (score 1):

In 1918, the region of Galicia went from Austria-Hungary to Poland (to keep it short), and today Lviv is part of the Ukraine. I would guess that the records are to be found in Polish or Ukrainian archives.

The FamilySearch wiki has a short page on the region [(see here)](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Austrian_Poland_(Galicia),_Austro-Hungarian_Empire_Genealogy), which essentially links to the main Polish search portal, Szukaj w Archiwach, and the archives of Lviv.

If you know your father's religion (or rather, his parents one) at birth, my advice (very basic, I have to admit) is to follow the steps in the FamilySearch wiki, and look in Szukaj for civil registration documents from Lviv.